# Can't sheet with button in ListView SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list. In the List there are 2 buttons.
I want to click on each button to present another view with Sheet.
When I first click it it works, but the second time or another tap button it doesn't present the view. Hope you can help me.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzsst.png)

[My design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdgVZ.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Read up on how to use Buttons and sheets. Typically Buttons triggering a sheet is used like this:

EDIT: with suggestion from Philip Dukhov, replace:

```
        Button("Learning") {
           
                }.sheet(isPresented: $isLearning, content: {
                    LearningView()
                })
        .onTapGesture {
            self.isLearning = true
        }
```

with:

```
    Button(action: {isLearning = true}) {
        Text("Learning")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isLearning) {
        LearningView()
    }
```

and do the same for "Test" button, with "isTest" instead of "isLearning" and "TestViewCategory()" instead of "LearningView()".

EDIT 2:

Update "TestView" with:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var title = ""
    let models = modelItems
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(models) { model in
                    TopicList(model: model)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(title, displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
        }
        .animation(.spring())
    }
}
```

EDIT 3: here is the test code that works for me:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TestView()
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    
    @State var isLearning: Bool = false
    @State var isTest: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {isLearning = true}) {
                Text("Learning")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isLearning) {
                Text("LearningView")
            }
            .font(.system(size: 16))
            .frame(width: 132 , height: 48)
            .background(Color(.white))
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                    .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9259920716, green: 0.9261471629, blue: 0.9259716272, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 1)
            )
            Button(action: {isTest = true}) {
                Text("Test")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isTest) {
                Text("TestViewCategory")
            }
            .font(.system(size: 16))
            .frame(width: 132 , height: 48)
            .background(Color(.white))
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                    .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9259920716, green: 0.9261471629, blue: 0.9259716272, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 1)
            )
        }
    }
}

struct TopicList: View {
    // for testing
    let model: String
    
    @State private var showSubItem = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: showSubItem ? "arrow.up.circle" : "arrow.down.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            showSubItem.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                
                VStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("title")
                            .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 24))
                            .padding(.top,9)
                            .padding(.bottom,4)
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("Open date")
                                .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 12))
                            Text("Open date")
                                .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 12))
                            Text("Due date")
                                .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 12))
                            Text("Due date")
                                .font(.custom("Poppins-Regular", size: 12))
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.leading,17)
                    .frame(width: 320, height: 70)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    
                    if showSubItem {
                        ButtonView()
                        .padding(.top,12)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        .transition(.opacity)
                        .transition(.slide)
                        .padding(.bottom,13)
                    }
                }
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9259920716, green: 0.9261471629, blue: 0.9259716272, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 1)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var title = "nav title"
    let models = ["1","2","3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(models, id: \.self) { model in
                    TopicList(model: model)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(title, displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
        }
        .animation(.spring())
    }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work . isLearning = true. only works when inside onTapGesture, But when I change it, it still doesn't work

Comment: remove the onTapGesture, and show us the code you are using, not a picture.

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you try that.

Comment: you don't need to set `isLearning = false` by hand, as  you're passing binding to `isPresented` and it's gonna be set to false when dismissed

Comment: I followed you, but it still doesn't work :((

Comment: what exactly is not working? What error do you get? works well for me.

Comment: it doesn't give an error, it just doesn't work like i said in the title

Comment: are you saying that the sheet do not show?

Comment: no, it still shows, but when i tap on the learning button and dismiss it, then i tap on the Test button it doesn't show up

Comment: ok, I see the problem, it comes from the List in "TestView". See my updated answer. You may also want to change the ".onTapGesture{...}" in "TopicList" to the `Image("arrow")` instead of the VStack.

Comment: I followed you, but it still doesn't change

Comment: I just updated the code, you can copy it and try to build it, I'm having the same problem

Comment: I've updated my answer with test code that works for me.

Comment: i followed you but it still only present when i tap on first button, tap on other button it doesn't show up

Comment: your method, I have used it before, but it still doesn't work

Comment: To be clear, is the code you are using "exactly" what I posted, 
or my code is mixed in with some other code that you use. 
I'm asking because it works very well for me, tested on real devices, mac iphone ipad. 
Can you tell us what system you are using, macos, ios xcode etc....
Maybe on older systems it is different. I'm on macos12, xcode13, ios15.

Comment: I followed you, but it's still the same. I am using Xcode12, ios13

Comment: I understood why it failed, because it only works from ios 14, from ios13 it won't work

Comment: so from the beginning I didn't have any errors, just had to run from ios14. But I want my project to work from ios13